# Bitbake depends AAA packet, it will rdepends AAA-dev

Tags: bitbake

I add depends packet to a exist `.bb` file, such as add `DPENDS="AAA"` line to `.bb` file, when I compile the `.bb` file, it failed for `XXX rdepends on AAA-dev [dev-deps]`, and I search google, all the answer almost is add line `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-deps"` or `RDEPENDS_${PN}_remove = "AAA-dev"` to `.bb` file.

But my question is why? why one packet depend AAA packet, it should also `RDPENDS` AAA-dev, is there any other answer to fix this problem

The `bb` source file is:

```
inherit autotools qcommon
DESCRIPTION = "Daemon to handle AT commands"
DEPENDS = "glib-2.0 qmi qmi-framework qmi-client-helper ocean-link"

SRC_DIR = "${WORKSPACE}/atfwd-daemon/"
S = "${WORKDIR}/atfwd-daemon/"

PR = "r3"
EXTRA_OECONF += "--with-glib --with-common-includes=${STAGING_INCDIR}"

do_configure_append() {
    echo "/*This is compiled to generate, only look don't try*/" > ${S}atfwd_config.h
    echo "#ifndef _ATFWD_CONFIG_H_" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    echo "#define _ATFWD_CONFIG_H_" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h

#//<!-- ODM feature caogang@2015-07-13
    if [ "${PRJ_NAU8810}" = "NAU8810_CODEC" ]; then
        echo "#define NAU8810_CODEC" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    fi

    if [ "${FEATURE_ACDB_ENABLE}" = "true" ]; then
        echo "#define FEATURE_ACDB_ENABLE 1" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    fi

    if [ "${PRJ_XXX}" != "" ]; then
        echo "#define  ${PRJ_XXX}" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    fi
#//end-->
```

I add a `DEPENDS` on onenet pkg

```
inherit autotools qcommon
DESCRIPTION = "Daemon to handle AT commands"
DEPENDS = "glib-2.0 qmi qmi-framework qmi-client-helper ocean-link onenet"

SRC_DIR = "${WORKSPACE}/atfwd-daemon/"
S = "${WORKDIR}/atfwd-daemon/"

PR = "r3"
EXTRA_OECONF += "--with-glib --with-common-includes=${STAGING_INCDIR}"

do_configure_append() {
    echo "/*This is compiled to generate, only look don't try*/" > ${S}atfwd_config.h
    echo "#ifndef _ATFWD_CONFIG_H_" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    echo "#define _ATFWD_CONFIG_H_" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h

#//<!-- ODM feature caogang@2015-07-13
    if [ "${PRJ_NAU8810}" = "NAU8810_CODEC" ]; then
        echo "#define NAU8810_CODEC" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    fi

    if [ "${FEATURE_ACDB_ENABLE}" = "true" ]; then
        echo "#define FEATURE_ACDB_ENABLE 1" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    fi

    if [ "${PRJ_XXX}" != "" ]; then
        echo "#define  ${PRJ_XXX}" >> ${S}atfwd_config.h
    fi
#//end-->
```

The `onenet.bb` is:

```
inherit pkgconfig cmake
DESCRIPTION = "onenet sdk"
LICENSE = "PD"
PR = "r0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${WORKDIR}/git/LICENSE;md5=bae84cdd023be37582157d865da54cc6"
SRCREV = "065d98dd8de91544315d6167ce73626ce739666d"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/cm-heclouds/MQTT.git;protocol=https"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git/mqtt_sdk"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/usr/lib
    install -d ${D}/usr/include/onenet

    install -m 0644 ${B}/bin/libmqtt.so -D ${D}/usr/lib/

    for inc in $(find ${S} -name *.h ! -name 'cJSON.h'); do
        install -m 0644 ${inc} -D ${D}/usr/include/onenet
    done
}s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sanity check documentation explains this:

> dev-deps: Checks that all packages except -dev or -staticdev packages
>   do not depend on -dev packages, which would be a packaging bug.

It's telling you that in your current recipe "XXX" runtime-depends on "AAA-dev" and that this is a normally an error. You need to find out how/why this dependency is added before you can decide what the correct solution is.

Based on the added recipes: The issue seems to be that onenet build produces an unversioned ".so" file. This is typically a mistake (the actual library file should be e.g. "libmqtt.so.1.1" and the unversioned file should just be a symlink to the versioned one). I'm very surprised that you are not getting a fatal error on this issue when you build onenet. Are you suppressing the QA error for this?

Since you've managed to build onenet somehow, you now probably have a onenet-dev package that erroneously contains the actual library: The build system notices this during atfwd-daemon build, adds a runtime dependency to onenet-dev (because that's where the library is) and then the QA error triggers because normal packages should not depend on -dev packages.

Possible fixes:

- Either fix the onenet build system so it produces a versioned library, or
- Force the .so file to be packaged into the actual onenet package instead of onenet-dev, like this:

  ```
  FILES_${PN}-dev = "${includedir}/"
  FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libmqtt.so"
  ```

A bonus suggestion: Using directory variables instead of paths like  /usr/include and /usr/lib (like I did above) is a good "Best Practice".

Comment: I have symlink to versioned one and I'm still getting same error.